# Setting entire redux store data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Is it possible to set entire data at once into Redux store ?

Without having reducers to form entire store object.

Ex: getState() - gives the current store

Similarly, Is there any way to set the data into store ?

Usecase:

I would get entire redux store data from an API. This has to be inserted into the store.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want is loading the initial store state from an API.

It should be fairly easy, you just have to make sure that the initialization of the store is deferred until you have the response from the endpoint and then you use that as initial data to create the reducer(s).